# Can't I return a form custom error anymore with "Altering the Form Values before Submitting"?

Tags: react-admin, react-final-form

React-admin version 2 used redux-form. Together with the documentation ["Altering the Form Values before Submitting"](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Actions.html#altering-the-form-values-before-submitting) i created a custom button that returns a form error from a custom function, or does a save.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { crudCreate, SaveButton, Toolbar } from 'react-admin';
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';

const myValidate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (values.files < 1) errors.files = 'resources.Order.errors.files';

    return errors;
};

// A custom action creator which modifies the values before calling the default crudCreate action creator
const saveWithNote = (values, basePath, redirectTo) =>
    crudCreate('posts', { ...values, average_note: 10 }, basePath, redirectTo);

class SaveWithNoteButtonView extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        const { basePath, handleSubmit, redirect, saveWithNote } = this.props;

        return handleSubmit(values => {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const errors = myValidate(values);
                if (errors) { 
                    reject(new SubmissionError(errors))
                } else {
                    resolve( saveWithNote(values, basePath, redirect) );
                };
            }
            });

        });
    };

    render() {
        const { handleSubmitWithRedirect, saveWithNote, ...props } = this.props;

        return (
            <SaveButton
                handleSubmitWithRedirect={this.handleClick}
                {...props}
            />
        );
    }
}

const SaveWithNoteButton = connect(
    undefined,
    { saveWithNote }
)(SaveWithNoteButtonView);
```

Now in React-admin version 3 ["Altering the Form Values before Submitting"](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.0/CreateEdit.html#altering-the-form-values-before-submitting) Can't I do this anymore?
This code does not work:(

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import ProcessIcon from '@material-ui/icons/HeadsetMic';
import { useForm, useFormState  } from 'react-final-form';
import { SaveButton } from 'react-admin';

const validateProcess = (values) => {
    const errors = {};

    if (values.files < 1) errors.files = ['resources.Order.errors.files'];

    return errors
};

const SaveWithProcessButton = ({ handleSubmitWithRedirect, ...props }) => {
    const form = useForm();
    const formState = useFormState();

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const errors = validateProcess(formState.values);
            if (errors) { 
                reject(errors) 
            } else {
                form.change('status', "DRAFT");
                resolve( handleSubmitWithRedirect('show') );
            };

        });
    }, [form]);

    return <SaveButton {...props} handleSubmitWithRedirect={handleClick} label="ra.action.process" icon={<ProcessIcon />} />;
};

export default SaveWithProcessButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

I manage to do this. Try my code below, I hope it will works for also for you.

```
    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {

        if (!formState.valid) {
        form.submit();
        return;
      } else { ... your code goes here }

    }, [form]);
```